# Can I pass an array of arbitrary rank to a subroutine in Fortran?

Tags: arrays, fortran, gfortran, fortran90, netcdf

I'm writing a general output for a numerical model I've written. I produce arrays that are either 1,2,3 or 4 dimensions on unknown length. I'm running into issues in how to define the array in the subroutine (found in a different module).

```
gfortran -g -O0 -I/usr/include -c analysis.f90
analysis.f90:136:32:
 call write_netcdf('domain', domain, 'binary_cloud_domain', 0)
                            1
Error: Rank mismatch in argument ‘data_out’ at (1) (scalar and rank-4)
```

The error comes from this subroutine:

```
  subroutine binary_cloud_analysis

use cloud, only: cloud_domain, cloud_smooth_domain
use write, only: write_netcdf

real, allocatable, dimension(:,:,:,:) :: domain, smth_domain

allocate(domain(x_dim,y_dim,z_dim,t_dim), smth_domain(x_dim,y_dim,z_dim,t_dim))

call cloud_domain(domain)

if (cloud_smooth) then
  call cloud_smooth_domain(domain,smth_domain)
  domain = smth_domain
endif

call write_netcdf('domain', domain, 'binary_cloud_domain', 0)

end subroutine binary_cloud_analysis
```

At the moment in the subroutine write_netcdf I've assigned data_out as

```
  subroutine write_netcdf(var_name, data_out, output_name, output_type)

!--------------------------------------------------------------------------!
! input variables                                                          !
!--------------------------------------------------------------------------!

real(kreal), allocatable, intent (in) :: data_out
```

Understandably the compiler is taking this as a scalar as I haven't included a dimensions(:) type specifier because I don't know what type of array I'm passing in generality and I'd hoped it might be able to massage the dimensions due to the variable being allocatable. The output_type variable specifies what type of array we have i.e. 3d, 4d etc to help define the NetCDF file.

I think I would be able to do it by reshaping the array into a 1d array and then reshaping back based on defining the number of dimensions and passing the lengths but ideally I wouldn't have these additional steps. Is there a way the define an allocatable array in sufficient generality for these purposes?

Comment: Please use tag [tag:fortran] for all Fortran questions. Fortran 90 is just one very old version. There certainly is no such functionality in Fortran 90 (except assumed size arrays) but there might be one (theoretically) in higher versions. It will definitely be impossible with an `allocatable` dummy argument. You can also make a generic interface to several specific subroutines.

Comment: @Goods I think you have a mismatching problem. Please show the array size in the calling program and in the called program.

Comment: @gansub done, you're right that it's a mismatching problem but i'm not sure how to resolve it whilst maintaining the desired generality

Comment: The legacy escape clause for rank matching is sequence association.  It's not clear that the feature furthers whatever goals you have.

Comment: I concur @tim18. The solution may be very simple indeed, but it is not clear what you want to do with the array inside `write_netcdf` nor is it clear why you need the allocatable dummy argument. Please explain what is inside `write_netcdf`, show the code.

Comment: Just read it in as a one-dimensional array, and compute which elements to pick out.